# Automating the creation of sub-dataframe in Pandas (with classes?)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame and I want to create some sub-dataframes. Now I create 3 sub-datasets 'by hand', but I'd like to automate this process because I need to reuse the code and because in the future the sub-datasets could be more than 3.

Let's say this is my dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
 

data = {'line':['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'r', 'j', 'j', 'r'],
        'time':['10', '3', '5', '50', '10', '20', '7', '33', '42', '15', '25', '9', '81']}
 
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
 
# Print the output.
print(df)
```

And the result is:

```
   line time
0     a   10
1     b    3
2     c    5
3     a   50
4     a   10
5     b   20
6     b    7
7     b   33
8     c   42
9     r   15
10    j   25
11    j    9
12    r   81
```

I need to create 3 subdatasets, always excluding the values 'r' and 'j' in the column 'line'. This is what I'm doing right now:

```
a = df[~df['line'].str.startswith('r') & ~df['line'].str.startswith('j') & df['line'].str.startswith('a') ]

print(a)

  line time
0    a   10
3    a   50
4    a   10
```

---

```
b = df[~df['line'].str.startswith('r') & ~df['line'].str.startswith('j') & df['line'].str.startswith('b') ]

print(b)


  line time
1    b    3
5    b   20
6    b    7
7    b   33
```

---

```
c = df[~df['line'].str.startswith('r') & ~df['line'].str.startswith('j') & df['line'].str.startswith('c') ]

print(c)

  line time
2    c    5
8    c   42
```

As said, I'd like to automate this process. The idea I had was to create a class; something like that [EDITED CODE]:

```
class Line:
    line_r = df['line'].str.startswith('r')
    line_j = df['line'].str.startswith('j')
    
    def __init__(self, line): 
        self.line= df['line'].str.startswith('')
        
    def get_line(self):
        if df['line'].str.startswith('a'):
            return df[~line_r & ~line_j & (self.line)]
        elif df['line'].str.startswith('b'):
            return df[~line_r & ~line_j & (self.line)]
        elif df['line'].str.startswith('c'):
            return df[~line_r & ~line_j & (self.line)]
        else:
            pass
```

But when I try to call it I get an error:

```
line_a = Line('a')

line_a.get_line()
```

the error is:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I think that the problem is in the use of the class to achieve the output...
Moreover, the process is not automated: if in the future I'll need 50 sub-dataframes, I have to write 49 'elif', and it is not so good...

Indeed, if I use a 'for cycle' I get the same error:

```
for s in df[~df['line'].str.startswith('r') & ~df['line'].str.startswith('j') & df['line'].str.startswith('s')]:
    if s == a:
        print('Hello')
```

Error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

What do you think? Any suggestions?

Comment: What should `self.phase` refer to? It doesn't seem to be well defined. How do you want to split the dataframes in the future? Based on the first character in `line`?

Comment: sorry, it has to be 'self.line' as you suggested. I've edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the following code.

Keep in mind that need to be very careful with this method as you are forcing an overwrite of the GLOBAL variables `a`,
`b`, and `c`.

```
for let in ["a","b","c"]:
    globals()["{}".format(let)] = (df[~df['line'].str.startswith('r') & 
                                      ~df['line'].str.startswith('j') & 
                                       df['line'].str.startswith('{}'.format(let))])
```